# Gatsby site 'page not found' when deploy on Netlify or Surge

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, surge.sh

I could run on localhost, however the site could not show up on Netlify and Surge as I tried to push it on Git. Feel free to check my code: https://github.com/treycwong/bean-tracker

I'm not sure if it's partly due to the dependencies in package.json or if I need to install Yarn? If so, some guidance will be helpful.

1. Added build settings on Netlify
2. Removed yarn.lock

With Surge, I've followed the [instructions](https://surge.sh/help/getting-started-with-surge), I've deployed it successfully but still the page shows 'page not found'.

Comment: Deploying your code files or your build directory?

Comment: Without any information how you configured `surge.sh`, I would recommend asking a separate question with more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your Netlify setting should be as follows, if you are not going to use yarn.

Publish location: `public`
Build command: `npm run build`

`/netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  publish = "public"
  command = "npm run build"
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm not using Yarn. I have edited the settings for Netlify. How do I access /netlify.toml ?

Comment: I guess you can just create that `netlify.toml` file in the root of your project, and netlify will find it when you push to your repo.

Comment: Changed to npm (carryover). You can just add the netlify.toml at the root of the repo.

Comment: Thanks! Created the file netlify.toml and also corrected the Build settings: Build command: gatsby build, Publish directory: public.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but this could help more than one.

I've just deploy a Gatsby site to Netlify and I got the Page Not Found error.

I fixed it configuring the build settings as following:
[image]

Once I did it I got a Node error cause Netlify works by default with an old version. So I needed to force to use a newer one setting the Environment variable to the same I'm using locally:
[image]

Hope it helps to someone else!